# Viewing WF trace logs

Tags: iis, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, etw

We're encountering "silent" aborts when Windows Workflows (hosted in IIS) are persisted using SqlWorkflowInstanceStore.

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2022538 :

> If the service is self-hosted or web-hosted, this issue creates a
>   diagnostic trace. Additionally, exception errors and warnings are
>   generated in the Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) trace log.

That article resolved our first issue (attempting to promote a Boolean property), but now we're encountering a new issue with identical symptoms. In order to diagnose it, we need to view these trace logs.

In every case, I am not seeing these logs in Event Viewer. It's very possible I'm not looking in the right place, or that I have to enable something first.

- How can I view these logs?
- (Bonus question) How can I subscribe to the diagnostic trace in a workflow?
- (Bonus question 2) How can I view these logs if I am debugging the workflow in Visual Studio 2010 with the default web server (formerly Cassini)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ETW Tracking Provider writes its logs to the Analytics log under Application Server-Applications. [image: ETW Tracking Provider]

You can add standard .NET tracing using a trace source with name "System.Activities". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780495/tracing-in-wf4-doesnt-work/9107170#9107170) for an example config.

Now quite sure I understand the third question as viewing the logs is independent of the hosting application choosen.

Comment: Thank you! After I enabled the Analytic log it's logging what appears to be irrelevant data, but adding a textListener to the Web.config creates a log specific to the workflow. However, I'm not finding an InstancePersistenceException in either log when I replicate the promoted Boolean issue. The closest I've found is "InternalReceiveMessage ... has completed in the 'Faulted' state" (with no details). Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using System.Activities.DurableInstancing and System.Runtime.DurableInstancing as diagnostics trace source names.

Comment: System.Activities.DurableInstancing worked. The issue was that DateTime.MinValue can't be used; dates must be year 1753 or later (SQL Server minimum). Thanks again.